# Conway's Game of Life: extraneous cells being printed when program run with only blank/dead cells (C/SDL2)

Tags: c, sdl-2, conways-game-of-life

To put it simply: When running my Game of Life program, it begins with an empty board of dead cells. If I run the simulation for a single cycle, it should stay empty, as there are no living cells for it to deal with. However, when I run my program, a few small dead cells become 'alive' in the bottom right corner. I'm not certain why this is but I believe it is either due to the way I am checking for living cell neighbours, or in how I display the cells. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define CELL_SIZE 10
#define GRID_WIDTH 100
#define GRID_HEIGHT 100
#define SCREEN_WIDTH (GRID_WIDTH * CELL_SIZE)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT (GRID_HEIGHT * CELL_SIZE)

typedef enum {ALIVE, DEAD} State;
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    State state;
} Cell;

// SDL related functions
SDL_Window *createWindow(char *title);
SDL_Renderer *createRenderer(SDL_Window *window);
void drawGrid(SDL_Renderer *r);
void drawCells(SDL_Renderer *r, int a[][GRID_WIDTH]);

// Game of Life functions
void updateCells(int a[][GRID_WIDTH]); // takes cells array as input
int countLivingNeighbours(int a[][GRID_WIDTH], int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Initialise SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    // Create window and renderer
    SDL_Window *window = createWindow("Game of Life");
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = createRenderer(window);

    // Setup event handling + mouse co-ordinate handling
    SDL_Event event;
    int mouseX, mouseY;
    bool mouse_left_down = false;
    bool mouse_right_down = false;

    // Set all cells to initial state of dead
    int cells[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
    int cx, cy;
    for(cy = 0; cy < GRID_HEIGHT; cy++){
        for(cx = 0; cx < GRID_WIDTH; cx++){
            cells[cy][cx] = DEAD;
        }
    }

    // MAIN LOOP //
    while(1){
        // Handle events/input
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0){
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT: // Check if user has quit
                    return 1;

                // Check if user is HOLDING left or right mouse button
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    switch(event.button.button){
                        case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT: mouse_left_down = !mouse_left_down; break;
                        case SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT: mouse_right_down = !mouse_right_down; break;
                    }

                // If user presses space, simulate a single change
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
                        updateCells(cells);

            }
        }

        // Get user mouse button input - left click gives life to cell at current co-ords, right click kills
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);
        if(mouse_left_down == true)
            cells[mouseY / CELL_SIZE][mouseX / CELL_SIZE] = ALIVE;
        else if(mouse_right_down == true)
            cells[mouseY / CELL_SIZE][mouseX / CELL_SIZE] = DEAD;

        // Set screen colour to white
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

        // Render white to screen (clear screen)
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        // Draw the grid and living cells
        drawGrid(renderer);
        drawCells(renderer, cells);

        // Update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    // Exit SDL and SDL_image
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

/*
1. Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by underpopulation.
2. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
3. Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
4. Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
*/
void updateCells(int a[][GRID_WIDTH]){
    int new[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
    int cy, cx; // vertical count, horizontal count

    for(cy = 0; cy < GRID_HEIGHT; cy++){
        for(cx = 0; cx < GRID_WIDTH; cx++){
            // Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by underpopulation.
            if(a[cy][cx] == ALIVE && countLivingNeighbours(a, cx, cy) < 2)
                new[cy][cx] = DEAD;

            // Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
            else if(a[cy][cx] == ALIVE && (countLivingNeighbours(a, cx, cy) == 2 || countLivingNeighbours(a, cx, cy) == 3))
                new[cy][cx] = ALIVE;

            // Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
            else if(a[cy][cx] == ALIVE && countLivingNeighbours(a, cx, cy) > 3)
                new[cy][cx] = DEAD;

            // Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
            else if(a[cy][cx] == DEAD && countLivingNeighbours(a, cx, cy) == 3)
                new[cy][cx] = ALIVE;

            else
                new[cy][cx] = DEAD;
        }
    }

    // Update all cells into new states
    for(cy = 0; cy < GRID_HEIGHT; cy++){
        for(cx = 0; cx < GRID_WIDTH; cx++){
            a[cy][cx] = new[cy][cx];
        }
    }
}

// THERE'S NO ERROR CHECKING HERE WHICH IS BAD
// Should ideally check if a cell even exists before checking its state
int countLivingNeighbours(int a[][GRID_WIDTH], int x, int y){
    int count = 0, cx, cy;

    for(cy = y - 1; cy <= y + 1; cy++){
        for(cx = x - 1; cx <= x + 1; cx++){

            // Ensure neighbouring cell is not out of bounds
            if(!(cy < 0 || cx < 0 || cy > GRID_HEIGHT || cx > GRID_WIDTH)){
                // If there is a living neighbouring cell, add to count
                if(a[cy][cx] == ALIVE)
                    count++;

                // disregard current cell as it is not a neighbour
                if(a[cy][cx] == ALIVE && cx == x && cy == y)
                    count--;
            }


        }
    }

    return count;
}

void drawGrid(SDL_Renderer *r){
    // Draw vertical grid lines
    for(int v = CELL_SIZE; v < SCREEN_WIDTH; v += CELL_SIZE){
        // Set draw colour to grey
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 110, 110, 110, 110);

        // Draw vertical line
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(r, v, 0, v, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }

    // Draw horizontal grid lines
    for(int h = CELL_SIZE; h < SCREEN_HEIGHT; h += CELL_SIZE){
        // Set draw colour to grey
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 110, 110, 110, 110);

        // Draw horizontal line
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(r, 0, h, SCREEN_WIDTH, h);
    }
}

void drawCells(SDL_Renderer *r, int a[][GRID_WIDTH]){
    // Define cell width/height
    SDL_Rect cellRect;
    cellRect.w = CELL_SIZE + 1; // Same size as one cell +1 so it covers the grid line fully
    cellRect.h = CELL_SIZE + 1; // Same size as one cell +1 so it covers the grid line fully

    // Draw living cells
    int cx, cy;
    for(cy = 0; cy < GRID_HEIGHT; cy++){
        for(cx = 0; cx < GRID_WIDTH; cx++){
            if(a[cy][cx] == ALIVE){
                // Set cell x/y pos
                cellRect.x = cx * CELL_SIZE;
                cellRect.y = cy * CELL_SIZE;

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(r, &cellRect);
            }
        }
    }
}

SDL_Window *createWindow(char *title){
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        title,                  // Title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // Initial window x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, // Initial window y position
        SCREEN_WIDTH,           // Window Width
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,          // Window Height
        0                       // Flags
    );

    if(window == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create window. %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return window;
}

SDL_Renderer *createRenderer(SDL_Window *window){
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window,                     // Window
        -1,                         // Monitor index (-1 for first available)
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED    // Flags
    );

    if(renderer == NULL){
        printf("Failed to create renderer. %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return renderer;
}
```

Strangely, this only seems to happen when GRID_WIDTH and GRID_HEIGHT are set to higher values. It happens when both are 100, and the program just hangs/crashes if the GRID_WIDTH is set to 150, but setting them both to a lower value (I tested with 30) and everything works smoothly.

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? Use a debugger for that. At a minimum it will tell you where your program crashes or what it is doing when it is "hanging". If you have done that already then share what you have found.

Comment: `cells` is a locally defined array. It might be just to big to fit in your stack.

Comment: I noticed from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955950/conways-game-of-life-cell-changes-being-calculated-incorrectly-after-changing) on this topic, you never check that plus or minus one breaks the array boundary. Without looking again at the neighbour count function, you need to do 8 explicit tests for each neighbour, no loop.

Comment: This is *way* too much code to expect people to go through. You need to debug it to narrow the problem down. Interesting problem, but you haven't made it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Place debugger breakpoints in `updateCells` and watch each iteration.

Comment: . . . for example, `if(y > 0) { if(a[y-1][x] == ALIVE) count++; }` and so on. 8 similar tests, no loops.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Consider developing the habit of asking yourself "how can I simplify this program fragment?"  For example in `updateCells` you have four calls to count the cells. You could be calling it *once*. When you make that change then ask yourself again, how can I simplify the program fragment?  And then you will see that the entire loop body becomes `int c = countLiving...; new[cy][cx] = (c == 3 || c == 2 && (a[cy][cx] == ALIVE)) ? ALIVE : DEAD;`  And now you've reduced the number of lines in the loop by 80%; less code, less chances for bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>        // Ensure neighbouring cell is not out of bounds
>        if(!(cy < 0 || cx < 0 || cy > GRID_HEIGHT || cx > GRID_WIDTH)){
> ```

This check is wrong. If cy is equal to GRID_HEIGHT or cx is equal to GRID_WIDTH it is still out of bounds. That's because the bottom-right cell has coordinates GRID_HEIGHT-1 and GRID_WIDTH-1.

Of course, it should be:

> ```
>        if(!(cy < 0 || cx < 0 || cy >= GRID_HEIGHT || cx >= GRID_WIDTH)){
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed something so minor.